# Can't find bug in function

Tags: javascript

Input:

1. `inputData`: array of objects like `{ geometry: [ int, int ], text: string }`
2. `inputDictionary`: array of strings

Function must sort `inputData` by `geometry[0]`. `inputDictionary` acts as a filter. If `inputDictionary` doesn't have any of `inputData`s *text* - return 'Unreadable message', else return all texts as string separated by whitespaces.

Sample input :

```
[  
    {  
        geometry: [10, 20],  
        text: 'James'  
    },  
    {  
        geometry: [20, 40],  
        text: 'Bond'  
    },  
    {  
        geometry: [5, 40],  
        text: 'Bond'  
    }  
], ['James', 'Bond']
```

Sample output: `Bond James Bond`

I can't figure out what's can be wrong. 2 tests of 7 returns runtime error (I don't know what these tests are) Help, please!

```
function(inputData, inputDictionary) {
   inputData.sort((a, b) => a.geometry[0] - b.geometry[0]);

   let isReadable = true;
   const textMessages = inputData.map(item => {
      const message = item.text;
      if (isReadable && !inputDictionary.includes(message)) {
         isReadable = false;
      }
      return message;
   })

   return isReadable ? textMessages.join(' ') : 'Unreadable message'
}
```

Comment: What is this apostrophe? `’` try using that instead: `'`

Comment: Fixed, samples was just copypasted, it is not real tests

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and now it's working.

```js
function test(inputData, inputDictionary) {
   inputData.sort((a, b) => a.geometry[0] - b.geometry[0]);

   let isReadable = true;
   const textMessages = inputData.map(item => {
      const message = item.text;
      if (isReadable && !inputDictionary.includes(message)) {
         isReadable = false;
      }
      return message;
   })

   return isReadable ? textMessages.join(' ') : 'Unreadable message';
}

console.log(test([  
    {  
        geometry: [10, 20],  
        text: 'James'  
    }, 
    {  
        geometry: [20, 40],  
        text: 'Bond'  
    },  
    {  
        geometry: [5, 40],  
        text: 'Bond'  
    }  
], ['James', 'Bond']));
```

This is what I did:

- Replace `’` with `'` everywhere.
- Give the function a name (`test`) to make it a function declaration.
- Wrapped the test results in a `console.log` to make them visible without running some (unknown?!) unit tests.

Comment: It wasn't a problem. Bug is inside function logic. I just paste sample input and output here, all tests run on server